# Reformat Yahoo finance date?

Tags: php, yahoo-finance

I'm using http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s= to grab a company's stock prices and imbedding in their site. I have 2 issues with it:

1. Is it possible to reformat the date?  It's currently returned MM/DD/YYYY, and it would be great if I were able to reformat to return DD/MM/YYYY. Is this possible?
2. Also, the date is being returned *with* quotation marks, to literally return *"MM/DD/YYY"*. I'd really love to get rid of these quotation marks.

Any ideas?

Many TIA!

---

EDIT:

I'm using the following code:

```
<?php
$asxcode = 'TDO';
$price = file_get_contents('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=' . $asxcode . '.AX&f=l1');
$date = file_get_contents('http://finance.yahoo.com/d/quotes.csv?s=' . $asxcode . '.AX&f=d1');
echo '$' . $price . '<br/>' . $date;
?>
```

Comment: It helps to provide the actual URL and data we're supposed to be looking at.

Comment: Apologies - I had assumed this would be easier than it perhaps is.

Comment: It's not that it's hard, it's that there's probably a better way to do it.

Comment: just a friendly reminder.
be nice to yahoo and your server and do caching of those contents.
maybe a few minutes would do :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
//get rid of the quotation marks
$yahoo_date = trim($yahoo_date, '"');

//will recognize yahoo's format and convert to a timestamp 
$timestamp = strtotime($yahoo_date); 

//you can now format it in any way you want
$reformatted_date = date('d/m/Y', $timestamp);
```

Comment: Interestingly, when I try this, I get the date 01/01/1970!

Comment: Do you have the date in a string? When you do a `var_dump` of it (before this code), what do you get?

Comment: I get:  string(14) ""11/26/2010" "

Comment: Oh I see, Yahoo returns some garbage in the date. Replace the `trim` line with this: `$yahoo_date = trim($yahoo_date, "\"\r\n");`

Comment: Well, that got rid of the quotation marks, but the reformatting still isn't working. Am I trying to do the impossible?

Comment: You're welcome, glad it worked. Very wtf of Yahoo to return such dirty data.